# Selecting a floating value yields incorrect results

Tags: mysql, floating-point

Consider the following.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `docs` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `qty` float NOT NULL,
  `price` float NOT NULL,
  `rebate` float not null,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `docs` VALUES
  (1,1,43616.7,0);

SELECT SUM(qty * (price - price * rebate/100)) AS endval
FROM docs
```

Instead of returning 43616.7 as expected, this query gives back 43616.69921875 (on some machines 43616.671875). Demo fiddle can be [found here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gUnwQaHBNTjXPrK4bnu65M/0).

Why is this happening? I would expect it to work like this (apologies for actually typing out something as basic as this):

```
1 * (43616.7 - 43616.7 * 0 / 100) = 1 * (43616.7 - 0) = 43616.7
```

I realize that I could overcome the issue by going with `decimal (10,2)` for my columns, I'm just wondering what's causing this unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Study the difference between precise and approximate numeric datatypes.

Comment: Here's another useful documentation page to study: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-float.html

Comment: Thank you all, I will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Do not use `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE` for money; use `DECIMAL(m,n)`
- It seems like `qty` should be integral?
- The following, and most things like it are doomed to returning FALSE:

  ```
  WHERE float_col = 1.23
  ```

  This is due to `FLOAT` being stored in binary, but `1.23` is decimal.
- 43616.7 is almost at the range limit of `FLOAT`, which is about 7 significant digits.  (That constant is 6 "significant digits".)

Comment: Understood, and thank you. As far as `qty` goes, it should be a `DECIMAL(m,n)`, because of things such as 3.112 kilograms of bananas, 1.356 milliliters of something, etc.